# TinyOWS on IIS 7.5 as FastCGI does not see GET query string?

Tags: iis, tinyows, querystring

I'm trying to set up TinyOWS on IIS 7.5 as a FastCGI application.

I've got the binary allowed in 'ISAPI and CGI restrictions', configured the handler for my virtual directory, set the TINYOWS_CONFIG_FILE environment variable for the TinyOWS FastCGI application.

The problem is, if I send some basic HTTP GET request like

```
http://localhost/[path to my virtual dir]/tinyows.exe?SERVICE=wfs&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&version=1.0.0
```

The response is always an ows:ExceptionReport with:

```
<ows:ExceptionText>Service Unknown</ows:ExceptionText>
```

If I configure tinyows to log everything the logfile looks like this:

```
[Fri May 09 16:10:42 2014] [EVENT] == FCGI START ==
[Fri May 09 16:10:42 2014] [QUERY] (null)
[Fri May 09 16:10:42 2014] [ERROR] Service Unknown
[Fri May 09 16:10:44 2014] [QUERY] (null)
[Fri May 09 16:10:44 2014] [ERROR] Service Unknown
```

So it seems like the QUERY_STRING environment variable is not set properly for the FastCGI.

Quick search in TinyOWS source on Github seems to confirm this: https://github.com/mapserver/tinyows/blob/38510100f539a80b26f707dcc0c458982050f9a6/src/ows/ows.c#L382

Most probably i just misconfigured IIS in some way... Does anybody have some idea?

Comment: Did you try your request using `SERVICE=WFS&` that is using upper case `WFS` as required by the WFS standard, as some servers strictly adhere to this requirement